# Puzzling Error on Iphone AddSubView function

Tags: iphone, view

```
    if(popup != nil) {
        [popup.view removeFromSuperview];
        [popup release];
    }
    popup = [[OfferPopup alloc] initWithNibName:@"OfferPopup" bundle:nil];
    popup.offer = offer1;
    popup.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:popup.view];
```

1)The App crashed when trying to do the addSubView popup.view

2)I stepped through the code and checked offer1 is valid, popup is valid has a memory address. popup is a view controller.

3)The current module is a viewcontroller too.

4)The App crashed due EXEC_BAD_ACCESS.

5)I used performance tool and enabled Zombie checking, and ran it, again the app crashed without the performance tool indicate where the reference count goes wrong.

I am puzzled as how to troubleshoot.

Comment: what does it show in crash log?

Comment: I don't think we have enough information to help you. Everything looks fine, your problem must be somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Check if Popup xib file exists, or see if you are naming it right in your initialisation code. See if the viewController class is correctly assigned in File Owner in IB.